# PDF library for modifying low level COS objects

Tags: library, pdf, c#, .net

I would like to associate a PDX search catalog file with a PDF document.
Apparently there is currently no library that supports this out of the box, so what I have to do is manipulate the `/Search` entry in the document directly.
I know next to nothing about the PDF standard, so a library I can access from .NET code that would encapsulate most of the details for me would be great.

This is what the structure looks like:
[image: PDF structure]

Answer (score 0):

With PDFNet you can easily insert/edit a PDF like you are looking for.

https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples/cs/SDFTest?platforms=windows
https://www.pdftron.com/pdf-sdk/windows-library

There is also Universal Windows Platform, and Xamarin, versions available if you are looking to do this on mobile.

https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/uwp/guides
https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/xamarin/guides

Answer (score 0):

[XFINIUM.PDF](https://xfiniumpdf.com/xfinium-pdf-crossplatform/xfinium-pdf-overview.html) library includes a COS API that lets you create custom structures in PDF files.

The code below shows how to build the Search structure in your sample:

```
// Create a new document.
PdfFixedDocument document = new PdfFixedDocument();
// Or load an existing document.
// PdfFixedDocument document = new PdfFixedDocument("sample.pdf");

// Fill the document information.
document.DocumentInformation = new PdfDocumentInformation();
document.DocumentInformation.Author = "XFINIUM Software";
document.DocumentInformation.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
document.DocumentInformation.ModifyDate = DateTime.Now;
document.DocumentInformation.Creator = "XFINIUM.PDF COS objects sample";
document.DocumentInformation.Producer = "XFINIUM.PDF Toolkit";
document.DocumentInformation.Title = "XFINIUM.PDF COS objects sample";
document.DocumentInformation.Subject = "XFINIUM.PDF sample code";
document.DocumentInformation.Keywords = "xfinium.pdf, pdf, sample";

// Create the /Search structure
PdfCosDictionaryContainer cosSearchDictionary = new PdfCosDictionaryContainer();
document.CosDictionary["/Search"] = cosSearchDictionary;

PdfCosArray indexesArray = new PdfCosArray();
cosSearchDictionary["/Indexes"] = indexesArray;

PdfCosDictionaryContainer indexDefinitionDictionary = new PdfCosDictionaryContainer();
indexesArray.Add(indexDefinitionDictionary);

indexDefinitionDictionary["/Name"] = new PdfCosName("/PDX");

PdfCosDictionaryContainer indexFileDictionary = new PdfCosDictionaryContainer();
indexDefinitionDictionary["/Index"] = indexFileDictionary;

indexFileDictionary["/Type"] = new PdfCosName("/Filespec");
indexFileDictionary["/F"] = new PdfCosString("c:\\Folder1\\Folder2\\index.pdx");

PdfPage page = document.Pages.Add();

document.Save("D:\\Temp\\Sample_SearchIndex.pdf");
```

The /Search structure can be seen in the image below:

[image: XFINIUM.PDF Inspector]

Disclaimer: I work for the company that develops the library.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, didn't see the replies earlier.
I was able to solve this using [PdfSharp](https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp).

Code posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51127552/how-to-associate-search-catalog-file-pdx-with-pdf-document/51177573#51177573